# resize a Matrix after created it in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-resizing

I'm new to OpenCV and I was looking at the Canny tutorial for Edge Detection. 
I was looking on how to resize a `mat` just created. The code is this:

```
 src = imread( impath );
 ...
 dst.create( src.size(), src.type() );
```

now I tried to resize the mat with this:

```
resize(dst, dst, dst.size(), 50, 50, INTER_CUBIC);
```

But it does not seems to change anything.

My doubts are two : 
**1** : Am I doing well calling `resize()` after `create()` ?
**2** : How can I specify the dimensions of the `mat` ?

My **goal** is to resize the image, if it was not clear

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You create `dst` mat with the same size as `src`. Also when you call `resize` you pass both destination size and `fx/fy` scale factors, you should pass something one:

```
Mat src = imread(...);
Mat dst;
resize(src, dst, Size(), 2, 2, INTER_CUBIC); // upscale 2x
// or
resize(src, dst, Size(1024, 768), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC); // resize to 1024x768 resolution
```

**UPDATE:** from the `OpenCV` documentation:

> Scaling is just resizing of the image. OpenCV comes with a function
>   cv2.resize() for this purpose. The size of the image can be specified
>   manually, or you can specify the scaling factor. Different
>   interpolation methods are used. Preferable interpolation methods are
>   cv2.INTER_AREA for shrinking and cv2.INTER_CUBIC (slow) &
>   cv2.INTER_LINEAR for zooming. By default, interpolation method used is
>   cv2.INTER_LINEAR for all resizing purposes. You can resize an input
>   image either of following methods:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg')
res = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=2, fy=2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
#OR
height, width = img.shape[:2]
res = cv2.resize(img,(2*width, 2*height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Also, in `Visual C++`, I tried both methods for shrinking and `cv::INTER_AREA` works significantly faster than `cv::INTER_CUBIC` (as mentioned by `OpenCV` documentation):

```
cv::Mat img_dst;
cv::resize(img, img_dst, cv::Size(640, 480), 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA);
cv::namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cv::imshow("Contours", img_dst);
```